# Efficient way to combine two extremely long lists in python

Tags: python, list

In python, we have two long lists each sorted and with more than around 20 million items and are **different** in **only a few items**.

```py
list_1 = [
    ...,  ## 20 million items common between the two lists
    'item_a',
    'item_b',
]

list_2 = [
    ...,  ## 20 million items common between the two lists
    'item_c',
    'item_d',
]
```

What I have is mind is to combine these two to get:

```py
combined = sorted([
    ...,  ## 20 million items common between the two lists
    'item_a',
    'item_b',
    'item_c',
    'item_d',
])
```

What I've tried is:

```py
combined = sorted(
    set([
        *list_1,
        *list_2,
    ])
)
```

but the problem is it takes too long to finish (for me it took around 50 minutes).

What's a more efficient way to do so?

---

Updates:
I tried these solutions provided on this page:

```py
## 1. by Cow
import itertools
all_ = [list_1, list_2]
combined = sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_)))

## Results: no improvements in time
```

```py
## 2. by Joooeey
combined = sorted(set(list_1) | set(list_2))

## Results: no improvements in time
```

Comment: Can you prepare an [mcve] that illustrates your problem for us to play around with? The example would have to include long lists, obviously.

Comment: Have you tried `sorted(set(list_1) | set(list_2))`?

Comment: From your attempt it looks like you assume that either list cannot contain duplicates. Is that guaranteed?

Comment: @Joooeey That's right. The duplicates have already been taken out.

Comment: Any approach with sets will not retain duplicates - so if you go that route, you can skip taking out duplicates in advance.

Comment: Actually, each list has unique items only. But when merged, those 20 million items in the new list will be duplicates and have to be taken care of.

Comment: @Cow I gave itertools a try, but it made no difference

Comment: So the not-common elements are at the end of each input list and are supposed to be at the end of the result list? The code you tried makes no attempt to achieve that.

Comment: How much are "only a few"?

Comment: What are the items? Are they strings? How large are they?

Comment: @KellyBundy May vary, but maybe around a thouasnd. All items are of the same type and length.

Comment: How long does your attempt take without the `sorted`? (I.e., just `set([*list_1, *list_2])`?

Comment: What is that type?

Comment: @KellyBundy String. They're all IPs.

Comment: That should be much faster than 50 minutes. Are you running into memory issues?

Comment: @KellyBundy As I checked now, it takes up to 16GB of RAM

Comment: And is that an issue for you? I don't know how much RAM you have.

Comment: No it's not an issue. The server comes with 64GB of RAM. The only thing I care about is to lower the amount of time.

Comment: I did a test with 2 million random IP strings. Your code took ~3.5 seconds. Those 50 minutes for ten times more elements without memory issues are unreasonable. I suspect there's something going on that you haven't told us.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why your code is slow is the use of the `sorted` function, which costs an average time complexity of *O(n log n)*.

Since you mentioned in the comments that the two input lists are pre-sorted, you can achieve a linear time complexity by using [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) instead of `sorted`. And to de-duplicate a sequence while keeping the order, you can use `dict.fromkeys` instead of `set`:

```
import heapq

combined = list(dict.fromkeys(heapq.merge(list_1, list_2)))
```

Comment: Actually, we need the combined list to be sorted. But the two lists we currently have are pre-sorted. I just have to make sure if the code above keeps the order.

Comment: So my assumption that the two input lists are pre-sorted is valid, in which case `heapq.merge` can indeed help you merge the two lists while keeping the combined list sorted in a linear time complexity. Have you given the solution above a try?

Comment: I just did on smaller lists and it does keep the order.I will do the same on the server and now should also compare how long it takes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two lists differ in only a few items, a more efficient approach would be to obtain those few items that `list_2` has but `list_1` doesn't, and sort `list_1` with those few extra items joined.

Since you mentioned in the comments that the input lists are pre-sorted, and Python's `sorted` function uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Analysis), which can practically sort in a linear time complexity when the input is almost pre-sorted, the overall time complexity of this approach would be linear as well:

```
combined = sorted(list_1 + list(set(list_2).difference(list_1)))
```

or you can use `itertools.chain` to avoid the overhead of creating an intermediate list:

```
from itertools import chain

combined = sorted(chain(list_1, set(list_2).difference(list_1)))
```

Comment: Oops yes absolutely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the two input lists only differ at the ends as you illustrated in the question, and since the two lists are pre-sorted and contain no duplicate as you mentioned in the comments, an efficient approach would be to iterate an index from the end of the shorter of the two lists to arrive at the index of the last common item, with which we can obtain the slice of the common items and the slices the differ. We can then use `heapq.merge` to sort just the slices that differ, and join it with the slice of the common items:

```
import heapq

def combine(l1, l2):
    for i in reversed(range(min(map(len, (l1, l2))))):
        if l1[i] == l2[i]:
            return l2[:(end := i + 1)] + list(heapq.merge(l1[end:], l2[end:]))
```

so that:

```
list_1 = [*range(10), 10, 11, 13, 15]
list_2 = [*range(10), 12, 14]
print(combine(list_1, list_2))
```

outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/FTgXM2

Comment: How about skipping the tail of the longer list (as much as it's longer) and just comparing i1 and i2 directly, without a dict? Btw, can you reproduce their time? I'm surprised that it takes anywhere near 50 minutes.

Comment: I agree that the OP's benchmark doesn't sound right on any modern environment unless the host's resources are extremely heavily shared with other users, but I went ahead to post answers anyway since it is clear that the OP's current solution is far from optimal given the characteristics of the input.

Comment: With tail I really just mean the longer part. Just considering the lengths, not any element values. Something like [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVBBasMwEKRXvWKPVuMEy22gGPSInIMobrNuRGzZXSsBv6UXX9pH5TVZSUlL6MKCpJ2Z1czXzzD5fe_m-fvom-XL-WFju6EnD3ush08hdtjAe9-9WYdZq3JoS1kJ4EoX0DAyGnfZbZrDASfdopMR1vQEFqwDwhPSyECq3QdroWOGlFe1ULZh0a01oDUL8eFvFMew0KDungj9kVwAV0xbQGtHn90hQkUnqw4prOUFlcmjfmWkFCJwXhX72D6mn6mCPaiCmw2pJ-61SajyH6rkfjZiIOt89htTVMwhcaRMyV4DvgV9AQ) (switched to pure index looping since I think that's easier here).

Comment: Ah yes how funny I figured it out only a minute after I made the comment asking you for a better explanation.

Comment: Updated my answer with the solution I arrived at a minute after I made that comment asking for a better explanation, which basically looks the same as yours. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah yes, even better. And here's a [while-loop version](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBbgIhFEXTLZv-wusOlGlk1MRMMl8yIc2o6LwEGESM8Vu6cdN-VL-mb6B2I8lNIO9wudzP73BLw-jv969LOlSbn5dXdGGMCQbThxNje3OA3ei26A23SoKtRcOAFkILDj13feDWeAmPsRB5fh3QGqJ6vwerOqyUhreWgLwtHsWnakHlYzTpEv2ENKhhDhbPiecc787E4xSgw0bLbNJoeohNyIeiKN0s9p4QtRAS1IJEadSStNaFqp-omrTSLET0if9_MjtKKHeEKL381fOo6Rc), not sure what I like better.